# Company name in the same line as topnav

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with setting up the company's logo (build as a h1 and quote) on the same line as my top navigation bar. Things don't want to overlap, I can either set it above or under the grey bar of topnav. Is there an wasy way to set up the logo (in code it's  div id="logo-holder") on the left side, while keeping the topnav on the same spot?

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;
    
}

#logo-holder { 
    float: left; 
    display: inline;
 }

    #logo-holder h1#logo a { 
        font-size: 22px; 
        font-weight: normal; 
        color: #000; 
        line-height: 1px; 
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-top: 200px;

     }

        #logo-holder p#quote { 
            font-size: 10px; 
            color: #777; 
            line-height: 3px; 
            padding-left: 3px; 
            letter-spacing: 0.12em;
         }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    text-align: right;
    color: #dfbf9f;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: #999999;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

        li a:hover {
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #d9d9d9;
        }

        li a:visited {
            background-color: #d9d9d9 !important;
        }

.welcome {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #01aef0 45%, #0090d7 100%);
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    font-size: 5em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 15px;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

#lorem {
    color: #80dfff !important;
    -webkit-margin-start: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-before: -15px;
    -webkit-margin-after: 10px;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    font-weight:300;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

.description {
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #808080;
}

#title {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

.ostatnie {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

footer {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 0 2px 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    float: left;

}
#footer-links { 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #dfbf9f;
}
#footer-links p a { 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #808080;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
    
.cl {
margin: 5px 0 0 80px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramaraja" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>

        <div id="logo-holder">
                <h1 id="logo"><a href="#" title="Company Name">Company Name</a></h1>
                <p id="quote">Free  Website  CSS  Template</p>
            </div>

<div class="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
     </ul>

</div>
 
 <div class="welcome">
  <header>
            <h1><em>welcome</em></h1>
   <h2 id="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>
        </header>
    </div>


<div class="grid">
 <div id="t1">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Who Are We?</em></h2>
  <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
 
 <div id="t2">
 <h2 id="title"><em>What We Do?</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
 
 <div id="t3">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Latest Projects</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="ostatnie">
 <div id="t4">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="t5">
 <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
 <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a> printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typeset</p>
 </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div id="footer-links" class="left">
        <p>
            <a href="#" title="Home">home</a>
            <a href="#" title="About Us">about us</a>
            <a href="#" title="Services">services</a>
            <a href="#" title="Solutions">solutions</a>
            <a href="#" title="Support">support</a>
            <a href="#" title="Partners">partners</a>
            <a href="#" title="Contact">contact</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cl"><p>&copy; Copyright Site Name</p>

    </div> 
  
</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement with `display: table` and `display: table-cell` properties. Try this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramaraja" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
        <div id="logo-holder">
                <h1 id="logo"><a href="#" title="Company Name">Company Name</a></h1>
                <p id="quote">Free  Website  CSS  Template</p>
            </div>

<div class="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
        <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
     </ul>

</div>
</div>
    <div class="welcome">
        <header>
            <h1><em>welcome</em></h1>
            <h2 id="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>
        </header>
    </div>


<div class="grid">
    <div id="t1">
    <h2 id="title"><em>Who Are We?</em></h2>
        <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="t2">
    <h2 id="title"><em>What We Do?</em></h2>
    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="t3">
    <h2 id="title"><em>Latest Projects</em></h2>
    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ostatnie">
    <div id="t4">
    <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="t5">
    <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a> printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typeset</p>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div id="footer-links" class="left">
        <p>
            <a href="#" title="Home">home</a>
            <a href="#" title="About Us">about us</a>
            <a href="#" title="Services">services</a>
            <a href="#" title="Solutions">solutions</a>
            <a href="#" title="Support">support</a>
            <a href="#" title="Partners">partners</a>
            <a href="#" title="Contact">contact</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cl"><p>&copy; Copyright Site Name</p>

    </div> 

</footer>
</body>

body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0px;
    display: grid;

}
.header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#logo-holder {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.topnav {
  display: table-cell;
}
#logo-holder {
 }

    #logo-holder h1#logo a { 
        font-size: 22px; 
        font-weight: normal; 
        color: #000; 
        line-height: 1; 
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;

     }

        #logo-holder p#quote { 
            font-size: 10px; 
            color: #777; 
            line-height: 3px; 
            padding-left: 3px; 
            letter-spacing: 0.12em;
         }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    text-align: right;
    color: #dfbf9f;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: #999999;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 24px;
    }

        li a:hover {
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #d9d9d9;
        }

        li a:visited {
            background-color: #d9d9d9 !important;
        }

.welcome {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #01aef0 45%, #0090d7 100%);
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

#lorem {
    color: #80dfff !important;
    -webkit-margin-start: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 15px;
    -webkit-margin-before: -15px;
    -webkit-margin-after: 10px;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    font-weight:300;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

.description {
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #808080;
}

#title {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
}

.ostatnie {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

footer {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 0 2px 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    float: left;

}
#footer-links { 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #dfbf9f;
}
#footer-links p a { 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #808080;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.cl {
margin: 5px 0 0 80px;
    }
```

Comment: It kinda worked. But now the header is spreaded, and the "logo" has white background, still not placed correctly. It's supposed to look like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/1200x/36/18/45/3618453c29096c6ec93a3db8ef4adfe6.jpg)

Comment: I have edited my answer to fix the issue you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! it looks much more like the original! Thank you for your help, I'll fix the rest by myself.

Comment: I still have some problems with setting up the logo in the right position. No padding/margin is working :/

Answer (score 0):

I using flex to solve your problems. I hope this would be useful.
I added a div with class "container" to contain div logo-holder and div topnav.

```css
body {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin: 0px;
        display: grid;
        
    }

.container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

    #logo-holder { 
        float: left; 
        display: inline;
        background-color: #ffffff;
     }

        #logo-holder h1#logo a { 
            font-size: 22px; 
            font-weight: normal; 
            color: #000; 
            line-height: 1px; 
            font-style: italic;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-top: 200px;

         }

            #logo-holder p#quote { 
                font-size: 10px; 
                color: #777; 
                line-height: 3px; 
                padding-left: 3px; 
                letter-spacing: 0.12em;
             }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        text-align: right;
        color: #dfbf9f;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: #999999;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 30px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 24px;
        }

            li a:hover {
                border-radius: 10px;
                background-color: #d9d9d9;
            }

            li a:visited {
                background-color: #d9d9d9 !important;
            }

    .welcome {
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #01aef0 45%, #0090d7 100%);
        padding: 50px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-margin-before: 0;
        -webkit-margin-after: 0;
        font-size: 5em;
        -webkit-margin-start: 15px;
        -webkit-margin-end: 15px;
        font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    h2 {
        margin: 0;
        color: #000000;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
    }

    #lorem {
        color: #80dfff !important;
        -webkit-margin-start: 15px;
        -webkit-margin-end: 15px;
        -webkit-margin-before: -15px;
        -webkit-margin-after: 10px;
        font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
        font-weight:300;
    }

    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-row-gap: 50px;
        grid-column-gap: 30px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 100px;
        margin-top: 75px;
        font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
    }

    .description {
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #808080;
    }

    #title {
        font-size: 38px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: 'Ramajana', serif;
    }

    .ostatnie {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 20px;
        grid-column-gap: 30px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 100px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

    footer {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px 0 2px 0;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 75%;
        color: #999999;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        float: left;

    }
    #footer-links { 
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0; 
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #dfbf9f;
    }
    #footer-links p a { 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        padding-left: 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #808080;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
        
    .cl {
    margin: 5px 0 0 80px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramaraja" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div class="container">
            <div id="logo-holder">
                    <h1 id="logo"><a href="#" title="Company Name">Company Name</a></h1>
                    <p id="quote">Free  Website  CSS  Template</p>
                </div>

           <div class="topnav">
             <ul>
               <li><em><a href="#home" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></em></li>
               <li><em><a href="#aboutus" style="text-decoration:none">About Us</a></em></li>
               <li><em><a href="#services" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></em></li>
               <li><em><a href="#solutions" style="text-decoration:none">Solutions</a></em></li>
               <li><em><a href="#support" style="text-decoration:none">Support</a></em></li>
               <li><em><a href="#partners" style="text-decoration:none">Partners</a></em></li>
               <li><em><a href="#contact" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></em></li>
           </ul>

          </div>
         </div>
     <div class="welcome">
      <header>
                <h1><em>welcome</em></h1>
       <h2 id="lorem">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h2>
            </header>
        </div>


    <div class="grid">
     <div id="t1">
     <h2 id="title"><em>Who Are We?</em></h2>
      <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
     <div id="t2">
     <h2 id="title"><em>What We Do?</em></h2>
     <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
     
     <div id="t3">
     <h2 id="title"><em>Latest Projects</em></h2>
     <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ostatnie">
     <div id="t4">
     <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
     <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a>. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>

     <div id="t5">
     <h2 id="title"><em>Some Title</em></h2>
     <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown <a href="https://templated.co/">Website CSS Templates</a> printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typeset</p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div id="footer-links" class="left">
            <p>
                <a href="#" title="Home">home</a>
                <a href="#" title="About Us">about us</a>
                <a href="#" title="Services">services</a>
                <a href="#" title="Solutions">solutions</a>
                <a href="#" title="Support">support</a>
                <a href="#" title="Partners">partners</a>
                <a href="#" title="Contact">contact</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="cl"><p>&copy; Copyright Site Name</p>

        </div> 
      
    </footer>
    </body>
```